# Hartshorne Lemma II 8.9.

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products, exact-sequence, free-modules

I am trying to understand the proof of Hartshorne's Lemma II 8.9:

> Let $A$ be a noetherian local integral domain, with residue field $k$
>   and quotient field $K$. If $M$ is a finitely generated A-module and
>   if $\dim_k M \otimes_A k = \dim_K M \otimes_A K = r$, then $M$ is free of rank $r$.

The proof goes:

> 1- $\dim_k M \otimes_A k = r$ so Nakayama's lemma tells us that $M$ can be generated by $r$ elements.

I can see it's a [consequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nakayama%27s_lemma) of Nakayama's lemma for local rings but I couldn't find a clear proof of this.

> 2- From the surjective map $\varphi : A^r \to M \to0$ and $R=\ker \varphi,  $ we get an exact sequence $0\to R\otimes K\to K^r\to M\otimes K\to 0$

How is that done?

> 3- Since $\dim_K M \otimes_A K = r$, we have $R \otimes K =0$

Why is that?

> 4- $R$ is torsion-free, so $R=0$

Why is $R$ is torsion-free and why it implies $R=0$
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Can you explain specifically whart is unclear about the proofs of 1 you know ? And can you show the work you've done in understanding 2-4 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Consider the submodule $M_0$ generated by the lifting of a basis of $M\otimes_A k$ in $M$. Tensoring the exact sequence
   $$0\longrightarrow M_0 \longrightarrow M \longrightarrow M/M_0 \longrightarrow 0$$ with $k$, you obtain that $\;M/M_0\otimes_Ak=0$, so Nakayama ensures that $M/M_0=0$.
2. It results from tensoring the exact sequence $\;0 \longrightarrow R\longrightarrow A^r \longrightarrow M\longrightarrow 0$ with the flat $A$-module $K$.
3. The map $ A^r\otimes_AK\simeq K^r \longrightarrow M\otimes_AK$becomes an isomorphism by hypothesis.
4. $R$ is a submodule of the *free* $A$-module $A^r$ and $A$ is a domain, so free modules are  torsion-free.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answer! 2,3 and 4 are clear to me now (2. follows from the fact that a field is always flat A-module and from the fact that tensor product commutes with direct sum and that $A\otimes_AK\simeq K$, 3.  follows from the fact that $A^r\otimes_AK\simeq K^r \longrightarrow M\otimes_AK$ is a linear map between same dimension vector spaces so it is surjective iff injective). However I still don't see what version of Nakayama's lemma are you using in 1.?

Comment: A field  which contains a ring is not necessarily flat over this ring, as far as I know, but rings of fractions are, and in particular  the field of  fractions of an integral domain. As to Nakayama's lemma, the version used is that if a module $E$ is finitely generated, $J$ is the Jacobson radical of $A$ and $E=JE$, then $E=0$. It  is applied to the situation where $A$  is local with maximal ideal $\mathfrak m$ and residual field $k$, using that $E\otimes_A k\simeq E/\mathfrak mE =0\iff E=\mathfrak mE$. Is it clearer?

Comment: Cristal clear, many thanks for your help!

Comment: although admittedly, saying $R$ is torsion free and then conclude $R=0$ does confuse the reader. The fact that $K$ is a flat $A$-module (so the canonical map $R\otimes K \to K$ is injective) implies that $R=0$ otherwise there is a $r\in R\backslash\{0\}$ such that $r\otimes 1 = 0$ which is identified as $r \in K$.

Comment: @quantum: *torsion-free* here is taken in the sense ‘no non-zero element is a torsion element’.

Comment: I understand. What I meant though is that it would have probably been more useful to a novice reader if Hartshorne wrote (although clear to an expert) that $K$ is a flat $A$ module before concluding everything.

Comment: I think it's a basic result that any ring of fractions is flat.